# Change Input field grabbing NAME

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I've searched about all I can.  I'm trying to change the text of an input field using its name.  I have found many ways to do it by ID like:

```
<script>
   function changeValue(o){
 document.getElementById('type').value=o.innerHTML;
}
</script>

<button id="technician" onclick="changeValue(this)">Technician</button>
<button id="developer" onclick="changeValue(this)">Developer</button>
<input type="text" id="type" name="type" value="change" />
```

But what I need to accomplish is for inputs without ID's.

Something along the lines of:

```
<script>
   function changeValue(o){
 document.getElementsByName('NAME').value=o.innerHTML;
}
</script>

<button id="technician" onclick="changeValue(this)">Technician</button>
<button id="developer" onclick="changeValue(this)">Developer</button>
<input type="text" name="NAME" value="change" />
```

Is there any way of accomplishing this?

***UPDATE***

I'm trying to expand on the javascript you guys helped me with.

The Snippet:

```
<script>
 function changeValue(o){
   document.getElementsByName('NAME')[0].value=o.innerHTML;
 }
</script>

<span onclick="changeValue(this)" style="cursor: pointer;">One</span>
<span onclick="changeValue(this)" style="cursor: pointer;">Two</span>
<img src='image.gif' onclick="changeValue(this.src)" />

<input type="text" name="NAME" value="SOMETHING">
```

The spans are working correctly, although I don't actually need them.  I will have all images once I figure this out.

I have tried a few ways, but what I can find is not directly related to my use.

The end goal is to get the img src into the text input with js, preferably somewhat how it already exists.  I feel it's really close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByName()` returns a collection. use `[]` to access individual elements

ex :

```
 function changeValue(o){
     document.getElementsByName('NAME')[0].value=o.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, exactly how I was looking for it.  Few minutes still before I can accept it.  But working great!

Comment: to expand on this, how would i go about using an img and grabbing only it's src? <img src='image.gif' onclick="changeValue(this.src)" /> doesnt work =/

Comment: i guess im not fully understanding, i looked it up some and i just cant get it to work.  Im ditching the buttons, and the spans the end goal is to have images do the same function the buttons did.  I updated the original post.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByName('NAME')` returns a list of elements by name. You need to provide the index as

```
document.getElementsByName('NAME')[0].value=o.innerHTML
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, this method worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Use document.querySelector like so

```
document.querySelector('input[name="NAME"]').value = o.innerHTML;
```

Comment: what are the benefits to using it this way?

Comment: This allows you to target an input by name, which is what you were asking

Comment: querySelector VS. getElementsByName?

Comment: well, this gives you just one element, so you don't have to index into the array anymore

Answer (score 0):

jQuery way

```
$('input[name="NAME"]').val("im changed!")
```